# Json generation and retrieval

Tags: java, javascript, json

How can I generate below given **json** sample through java servlet page? And then how to retrieve in **html- javascript** page?

Required Json sample:

```
[{user:"1s",item:123},{user:"2w",item:143},{user:"f2",item:125}]
```

Which can be used JsonArray or JsonObject? or both ..?

Comment: the json you wrote there is an array of three object, so...a jsonarray with three jsonobjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use json.org JSON library for Java. Create a JSON object, load it, pipe the string output (.toString()) to the output stream in the `doGet` method in your `HttpServlet`.

http://json.org/java/

On the JavaScript side, get the JSON string with `XMLHttpRequest` then convert it to a JavaScript object with `JSON.parse`.